# How to compare a date in entity framework to avoid rounding errors?

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, rounding-error

I have a .NET DateTime value that I write to a SQL Server database "datetime" field (and trust me, I WISH we were just using "datetime2(7)" that matches .NET's DateTime precision exactly, but we're not).

Anyway, I write the entity to the database and that particular field ends up being '2016-03-03 08:55:19.560'.

It's a last processing time, and I'm looking for other records that were processed **before** that time.  When I run an entity framework where clause, it ends up running a statement ending with "@p__linq__0='2016-03-03 08:55:19.5602354'" as the value it's comparing against, which ends up being slightly greater, even though these two values originate from the exact same DateTime instance.

I tried changing the time it's comparing against to an SqlDateTime, but then the lambda doesn't compile because it can't compare a DateTime? to a SqlDateTime.  SqlDateTime has comparison methods, but I don't know whether entity framework recognizes the functions.

I can't even cast between the two in entity framework, which just gives the error "Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Comment: What's the required accuracy of the time - to the nearest second? centisecond? millisecond?

Comment: There is no required accuracy.  The point is that if I have a model with a DateTime property named "Fred", it gets written to a database field of type 'datetime', which is less accurate and get's truncated.  If I then run a linq query using the same "Fred" property and compare it against the very field it was written to.... entity framework will populate the query parameter with a string representation of the date that has more digits of accuracy than what it wrote to the field, so the comparison to itself always fails.

Comment: When doing the comparison, I was able to fix it by casting the value to SqlDateTime first, then right back to DateTime.  That seems to truncate it the same way the comparison succeeds, but I'm not sure how reliable it is.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem. In my case I finally value the DateTime fields by using:

```
public static DateTime RoundedToMs(this DateTime dt) {
    return new DateTime(dt.Ticks - (dt.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond), dt.Kind);
}

public static DateTime RoundedToMsForSql(this DateTime dt) {
    DateTime n = dt.RoundedToMs();            
    return new DateTime(n.Year, n.Month, n.Day, n.Hour, n.Minute, n.Second, (n.Millisecond / 10) * 10);
}
```

And in the business code:

```
someEntity.SomeDate = dateValue.RoundedToMsForSql();
```

The point, in my case, is **sql datetime has a 3ms precision**, so I decided to remove millisecond unit.

Same extension may be used in the queries, well in fact to populate variables used in the queries.

```
var d = DateTime.Now.RoundedToMsForSql();
var q = from e in ctx.Entities where e.SomeDate <= d;
```

Comment: That's cool.  I ended up just doing this: `var truncatedDate= (DateTime)(SqlDateTime)originalDate;` and that seemed to work fine.  I even went further and just subtracted a whole second off in my particular case, because the value is a "last processed" time that I'd never want to process more than once a second anyway (it's supposed to be once every 30 minutes), so kicking it back a whole second is even more secure than kicking it back by the remaining milliseconds.

Comment: I had the exact same requirement/paradigm as you: last edit date. I choose to exploit the maximum precision because: a null probability does not exist :) (on problem less for later).